# Compare today's data with same day/time but previous week's data

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

For the given sample data, I need a formula to find the difference between E2-E7 which is comparing today's hourly data with exact time of the previous week.

P.S. `3/27 11.00 AM` has to be compared with `3/20 11.00 AM` not with 11.00 PM.

```
       C         D         E       F      G       H
Row-1 Date  Time           X1      X2     X3      X4
Row-2 3/27  11:00 AM    760197  408260  359812  77.55%
Row-3 3/27  10:00 AM    758371  369609  326323  78.00%
Row-4 3/27   9:00 AM    756123  313521  278248  78.31%
Row-5 3/27   8:00 AM    753097  232591  206849  78.26%
Row-6 3/21  11:00 PM    760197  408260  359812  77.55%
Row-7 3/21  11:00 AM    760197  408260  359812  77.55%
```

Comment: 3/21 and 3/27 are different days of the week, e.g., Thursday and Wednesday this year. I'm guessing you meant 3/20 and 3/27. Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Ohh yess.. thats typo! I mean to compare 3/27 and 3/20.

Comment: Im trying for a combination of Match and index... but struck with getting cell range reference for the rows of previous weeks day

Comment: is the data structured/sorted or is it just mixed? I mean do we know that todays row-number is always row-1 ? and week ago row-number is minus x-rows? I m thinking if we can use row-number to figure out one week ago rowid. It would minimize the complicity of the formula. Are you able to pick out this report in different way? or is it as it is...

Comment: Its Yes and No. All the rows are ordered (Today last hour will be on top) but there could be missing rows for one or more hours for any day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combine Date and Time (say in ColumnA) and in Row2 use:

`=IFERROR(E2-VLOOKUP(A2-7,A:E,5,FALSE),"")`

Copy down as required.

Comment: Great... it works!!!
But is there anyway we can do this combining Date&Time on the fly i.e. without having a separate column...? The format of the excel sheet is pretty standard, so dont want to mess it up

Comment: hmm...changing source is out of my way...anyway thanks for the update!

Answer (score 0):

This is an illustration of a solution, and could for sure be simplified.

But maybe you can use it...

[image]

As you see, the formulas used are:

```
=C2&D2  
=C2-DAY(7)   
=J2&D2  
=MATCH(K2,I:I,0)    
=E2-INDIRECT("E"&L2)
```

Hope it helps.